# How to configure ZeroBrane with Corona simulator on MacBook

Tags: macos-sierra, zerobrane

I installed Corona-36674 and ZeroBrane on a MacBook but I don't succeed to get the simulator working!
In the user.lua I wrote:

```
path.corona='/Applications/Corona-3664/Corona Simulator.app'
```

but the simulator is not launched!

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path needs to point to the actual executable; most likely something like this should work: `path.corona='/Applications/Corona-3664/Corona Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Corona Simulator'`. Also, if the Corona SDK installed in `/Applications/CoronaSDK/` folder, it will be found there automatically.

See the [interpreter path section in the documentation](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#interpreter-path) for details and examples.

Comment: Thank you. I've succeed to fix it. Now I have another problem! I had to reinstall ZeroBrane on WIndows and it doesn't point to default path of Corona!